# Regular expression, containing a name + "string" + number and nothing else

Tags: c++, regex

i want to filter some names that include a string e.g 
"name" followed by the string "- entire" followed by a number and nothing behind.
e.g.

1. myName - entire 23 (ok)
2. somethingElse - entire 24 (ok)
3. name - entire 25 blub (not ok, because of the string blub)
4. somethingElse - entire 25m (not ok, because of the m)

I tried "/ \w* - entire \d* /g"
that matches until the number, but how to check that after the number shall be empty, no digit, no letter or something else?

Comment: First you need word boundary: '\b'
How about search by the NOT ok case first? Then the rest will be ok case?

Comment: What regular expression engine are you using? and what does the `g` at the end do.

Answer (score 2):

Anchor the match to the end of the string with `$`: "/ \w* - entire \d* $/g"

Other comments:

- You probably want to anchor the start with `^`
- I am deeply suspicious of those `*` quantifiers.  You almost certainly want `+` (meaning "one or more").
- I would tend to replace the spaces with `\s*` or `\s+` to allow a variable number of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the regex in Javascript. Please check them and use them accordingly in C++

The regex is

```
/[A-z]+\s-\sentire\s\d+$/
```

Examples:

```
/[A-z]+\s-\sentire\s\d+$/.test('myName - entire 23'); //passes
/[A-z]+\s-\sentire\s\d+$/.test('somethingElse - entire 24'); //passes
/[A-z]+\s-\sentire\s\d+$/.test('name - entire 25 blub'); //fails
/[A-z]+\s-\sentire\s\d+$/.test('somethingElse - entire 25m'); //fails
```

Comment: Do you know what `[A-z]` is matching?

Comment: Yes. It matches all the alphabets from A to Z and a to z

Comment: No, it doesn't. It matches also special characters present between `Z` and `a`. Have a look at an ascii table.

Comment: In particular, assuming ASCII, it will match characters like `[`, `]`, and backslash.

Comment: In fact, I think that's wrong enough to downvote.  Comment if you fix it, and I'll remove the dv.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick support, now I have it correctly:
The expression is: `\w*\s*-\s*entire\s*\d*$`, and it works as expected.